# Zooming In/Out of a OpenGL ES 2D Game Scene

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

What's the best method for pulling back to show more of a view in a 2D OpenGL iPhone game? For instance, in Tiny Wings, when the bird flies toward the top of the screen the bird and the scenery pull back to simulate the bird going higher in the sky. Would this effect be better achieved by scaling all the sprites proportionally, or by using glOrthof? In any case, I'm assuming that the zoom-out factor is inversely proportional to the player's y position.

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly want to use `glOrthof` so all you're changing is how the camera sees the scene. This avoids recomputing all the normals and such in the scene, saving quite a bit of work. It's also easier for you to implement.